# Searching for small, wired keyboard

Tags: keyboards

I want to buy a **wired keyboard** to travel with, so I want a small sized one. I request for advices, please.

**Requirements**:

- **No wireless** keyboards in any manner (no bluetooth, infrared, radio... etc). This is a question about wired keyboards.
- **Foldable** keyboards accepted.
- USB and PS2 **connectors** accepted. Both would be fine.
- No need for **mouse**: it will increase the size of the keyboard, and this question is about **small** keyboards.
- It is logical that there will be some switch/keycap quality sacrificing, but not-too-bad **switch/keycap quality** would be preferred.
- **Thumb** keyboards accepted.

Comment: I have bad news for you.  There isn't a huge demand for wired small keyboards, the majority of travel keyboards, are not going to be wired.  Any non-wired keyboards are going to be keyboards that only work with specific products like the `Microsoft Surface Type Cover` and `Microsoft Surface Type Touch Cover` keyboards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a recommendation for you, I already have two (@home and @office) pretty good stuff. Available in black version too just search using that name. I also still enjoy the wired version. Depending on your location you can find that model in other countries too. If you want more real pictures just let me know. Hope that helps.

[Mini-78-Key-Ultra-thin-USB-Wired-Keyboard-for-Laptop-PC-White-Sliver](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Mini-78-Key-Ultra-thin-USB-Wired-Keyboard-for-Laptop-PC-White-Sliver-/272208003646)

Answer (score 2):

A simple google would do:

[https://www.amazon.com/Global-Marketing-Partners-FK205-Keyboard/dp/B000UZVL3K](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000UZVL3K)

Looks like a pretty decent one. Has a USB cable according to reviews and not made out of rubber

Comment: A good answer. It is hard to find a foldable or reduced-size keyboard as for today that has no wireless capabilites (so consuming batteries, needing drivers, not working at boot... etc). Only 20cm (if I understood correctly the specs) folded. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

[iClever BK05](https://www.iclever.com/products/BK05-Tri-Folding-Bluetooth-Keyboard) might fit the bill. It does have Bluetooth, but is also able to work via USB.